# Getting a point from begginning coordinates, angle and distance

Tags: java, math, vector, libgdx, rotation

I want to get a Vector containing a coordinate. I know my beginning coordinates, angle and distance. So far I've tried doing:

```
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(beginningX, beginningY).add(distance, distance).rotate(angle);
```

But it doesn't work as I expect it to. When the rotation isn't `0` the coordinates become big, and the ending point isn't where I expect it to be. I know this must be a simple problem, but I just can't solve it.

**EDIT:**
Tried doing:

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(beginningX, beginningY).add(distance, 0).rotate(angle);
```

(Adding `distance` to `x` only) Still no success.

Comment: Are you sure you need the angle? Let's say you have the vector (1,1), add (2,3) then you get (3,4). Isn't this what you're asking for or am I misinterpreting your question? EDIT: Just adding distance to the y-coordinate would be like adding a vertical vector to your existing one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you're doing it wrong: you need to rotate the distance vector and add it to the position vector:

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(beginningX, beginningY).add(new Vector2(distance, 0).rotate(angle) );
```

You might want to read up on vector math but basically it amounts to this (if I correctly understood what you're trying to do):

If you rotate a vector you're always rotating around point 0/0. Thus you'll want to create a vector that covers the distance from 0/0 to your distance on the x-axis:

```
0---------------->d
```

Now you rotate that vector by some angle:

```
       d
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 0
```

Then you offset that vector by your starting point, i.e. you add the two vectors (for simplicity I assume your starting point lies on the y-axis):

```
      d
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /   
s
|
|
|
0
```

Comment: @LórántGerber one can only guess ;)

Comment: Vectors are taught in math classes.  You just have to take the right ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate only the distance vector, rather than a sum of beginning and distance. Addition is the same in either order (commutative), so you can try this way:

```
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(distance, 0).rotate(angle).add(beginningX, beginningY);
```

Advantage: This chained call does not create a temporary Vector2 for the beginning position that would immediately become garbage for the garbage collector. Conserving space and garbage collection time will be important when your code handles millions of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple vector addition.  I'm assuming 2D coordinates, with angles measured counterclockwise from x-axis:

```
x(new) = x(old) + distance*cos(angle) 
y(new) = y(old) + distance*sin(angle)
```

Be sure that your angles are in radians when you plug them into trig functions.